# Mocking classes with template methods

Tags: c++, unit-testing, c++11

Is there any pattern for testing classes that use classes containing template methods in public api? I know that in dynamic polymorphism mocking interface is the solution like this:

```
struct Interface {
 virtual void foo() = 0; 
 virtual ~Interface() = default;
};

class TestedClass {
public:
  TestedClass(Interface& i) {}
  // ... rest of the class
};

struct IMock : public Interface {
 void foo() override {} 
};

void test() {
  IMock bar;
  TestedClass baz(bar);
}
```

But what can I do with something like below? Is there an idiomatic way to test this?

```
struct Interface {
 template<class T>
 void foo() {
   // do stuff depending on type
 }
};

class TestedClass {
public:
  TestedClass(Interface& i) {}
  // ... rest of the class
  // uses Interface foo with multiple types
};
```

Comment: You test the template, or a class, or whatever you want to test, and check the results, what exactly is your question, it is unclear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To allow mocking, in that case, you need

`template <typename InterfaceT> class TestedClass;`

so you can now have `TestedClass<Interface>` (for production) and `TestedClass<MockInterface>` (for testing).

```
struct Interface {
 template<class T>
 void foo() {
   // do stuff depending on type
 }
};

template <typename InterfaceT>
class TestedClass {
public:
  TestedClass(InterfaceT& i) {}
  // ... rest of the class
  // uses Interface foo with multiple types
};

struct MockInterface {
 template<class T>
 void foo() {
   // do mock-stuff depending on type
 }
};

void test() {
  MockInterface bar;
  TestedClass baz(bar); // Or pre CTAD of C++17: TestedClass<MockInterface> baz(bar);
}
```

Comment: not that I am super happy with such solution (template errors are horrible) but I guess it doesn't get any better than this